# Turn a string into 6 line block paragraph in classic asp

Tags: vbscript

I have just written the following code which works fine but I would like to know if there is an easy way to display a message in a block format.

Basically I have a string called message which contains a sentence:

> "This is a story of a little boy visiting the sweetshop for the first
>   time, this was a very exciting time for him as he's never been in a
>   sweet shop before and it was full of exciting thing to see and do, but
>   he wasn't allowed in the shop without his mummy."

Now I need to put this into a block paragraph of 6 lines all of 40 character (ish) each line must end in a full word.

I used the MID, REPLACE, DO & LOOP functions to achieve this but I would like to know if there is an easy way of doing it.

The main checker is

```
line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_1 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_1 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If

message = Replace(message,"","",line_counter)
```

I do this 6 times and store the results for each line in a variable called line_*.

So my question is, is there a simpler way of doing this?

Regards

Rick

Here is the code.

```
<%
message = "This is a story of a little boy visiting the sweetshop for the first time, this was a very exciting time for him as he's never been in a sweet shop before and it was full of exciting thing to see and do, but he wasn't allowed in the shop without his mummy."
Response.write message
Response.write "</P>"
line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_1 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_1 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If

message = Replace(message,"","",line_counter)

line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_2 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_2 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If

message = Replace(message,"","",line_counter)

line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_3 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_3 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If

message = Replace(message,"","",line_counter)

line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_4 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_4 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If

message = Replace(message,"","",line_counter)

line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_5 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_5 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If

message = Replace(message,"","",line_counter)

line_counter = 40

If Mid(message,line_counter,1) <> " " Then

    Do until Mid(message,line_counter,1) = " "
        line_counter = line_counter + 1
    Loop    
    line_6 = Mid(message,1,line_counter)
Else
    line_6 = Mid(message,1,40)
End If


Response.write "</P>"
Response.write line_1
Response.write "</P>"
Response.write line_2
Response.write "</P>"
Response.write line_3
Response.write "</P>"
Response.write line_4
Response.write "</P>"
Response.write line_5
Response.write "</P>"
Response.write line_6
%>
```

Comment: Why not just use an HTML paragraph `<p></p>` and style it accordingly, this isn't a Classic ASP issue. How you render the result is down to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get quite close to what you want using CSS. You can use a combination of `width` in `ems` to limit the number of characters per line and `overflow-wrap: normal` to force each line to only wrap if you have a complete word.

Something like this;

```
<%
Dim message: message = "This is a story of a little boy visiting the sweetshop for the first time, this was a very exciting time for him as he's never been in a sweet shop before and it was full of exciting thing to see and do, but he wasn't allowed in the shop without his mummy."
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Paragraph wrapping test</title>
    <style>
      p.block {
        width: 40em; 
        overflow-wrap: normal;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p class="block"><%= message %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Static Demo:

```css
p.block {
  width: 40em;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<p class="block">This is a story of a little boy visiting the sweetshop for the first time, this was a very exciting time for him as he's never been in a sweet shop before and it was full of exciting thing to see and do, but he wasn't allowed in the shop without his mummy.</p>
```

---

Another approach instead of `em` is `ch` which is defined on MDN as;

> the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph '0' (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's font.

This may give a more accurate approximation of 40 characters;

Static Demo:

```css
p.block {
  width: 40ch;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<p class="block">This is a story of a little boy visiting the sweetshop for the first time, this was a very exciting time for him as he's never been in a sweet shop before and it was full of exciting thing to see and do, but he wasn't allowed in the shop without his mummy.</p>
```

Comment: The main purpose of having the coding the way I did it, is to split the sentence into 6 variable all of 40 characters each.

Comment: Is this possible using your method?

Answer (score 0):

While I would use Lankymart's answer if the only problem is rendering the text, if you really need to "manually" split the text, then you can use something like (VBScript code written to be called using  `cscript.exe`)

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim message
    message = "This is a story of a little boy visiting the sweetshop for the first time, this was a very exciting time for him as he's never been in a sweet shop before and it was full of exciting thing to see and do, but he wasn't allowed in the shop without his mummy."

    WScript.Echo ".........1.........2.........3.........4.........5"

Dim line
    For Each line In WordWrap( message, 40 )
        WScript.Echo line
    Next 


Function WordWrap( inputText, lineLength ) ' as String()
Dim delimiter
    delimiter = Chr(0) & Chr(0)
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(.{1," & lineLength & "}|\S+?)(\s|$)"
        .Global = True
        WordWrap = .Replace( CStr(inputText), "$1" & delimiter )
        WordWrap = Split( Left(WordWrap, Len(WordWrap) - Len(delimiter)), delimiter )
    End With 
End Function
```

This simply uses a regular expression to search for the most adecuated wrap points, places a delimiter at the found points and splits the text using the delimiter.